# enter a password if 3 time wrong attempt If the user enters two incorrect passwords, but was able to provide the correct password for the 3rd time

Tags: javascript, while-loop

can anyone help me with this im just starting to learn JS
Create a program that will exit if the user enters an incorrect password thrice//If the user enters two incorrect passwords, but was able to provide the correct password for the 3rd time, reset your counter variable into 0

//3 incorrect enter of password, add alert("Your account has been blocked!");
heres what i have done so far

```
const userPass = "Password123";
let inputPass = prompt("Please enter your password:");
let counter = 0;

while (inputPass != userPass) {
    inputPass = prompt("Please enter your password:");
}

console.log("Thank you for providing the right password!");
```

Comment: You never do anything with `counter `

Comment: Try modifying the counter everytime a password is entered

Answer (score 1, accepted):

is this what you are looking for? https://jsfiddle.net/8e2k0ymh/

```
const userPass = 'Password123';
let inputPass = prompt('Please enter your password:');
let counter = 0;

while (inputPass != userPass && ++counter < 3) {
    inputPass = prompt('Please enter your password:');
}
if (counter == 3) {
    alert('Your account has been blocked!');
} else {
    alert('Thank you for providing the right password!');
}
```

Comment: Yes thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

```
const userPass = "Password123";
let inputPass = prompt("Please enter your password:");
let counter = 0;

while (inputPass != userPass && counter <3) {
    inputPass = prompt("Please enter your password:");
    counter++
}

if(counter < 3) console.log("Thank you for providing the right password!");
else console.log("Your account is blocked")
```

Answer (score 0):

I would run an if statement after submitting the password that checks to see if the password is correct. If not correct add to counter and check if the counter is equal to 3.

```js
if (inputPass != userPass) {
  counter++;
  if (counter >= 3) {
    inputPass = prompt('You have been blocked!');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you have the solution:

```js
const userPass = 'Password123'

let inputPass = prompt('Please enter your password:')
let counter = 1
const MAX_ATTEMPS = 3

while (inputPass != userPass) {
  if (counter < 3) inputPass = prompt('Please enter your password:')
  else {
    alert('Account has been blocked')
    break
  }

  counter++
}

counter = 1

console.log('Thank you for providing the right password!')
```

Note that the `counter` was modified from 0 to 1 and a new constant `MAX_ATTEMPS` was added.

Also an `if` statement was added to handle the 3 attemps in the `while` loop body.